# ENOBUFS error encountered while processing large file in NodeJS + Docker

Tags: node.js, docker, memory-leaks

I'm writing a nodeJS application that downloads large CSV files (>1M rows) from an S3 bucket, splits them into chunks and saves the chunks into smaller CSV files for further processing.

My application runs into a docker container and I'm encountering some memory issues.

This is the error I'm getting.

```
Job error occurred! Error: write ENOBUFS
at afterWriteDispatched (internal/stream_base_commons.js:156:25)
at writevGeneric (internal/stream_base_commons.js:139:3)
at Socket._writeGeneric (net.js:783:11)
at Socket._writev (net.js:792:8)
at doWrite (_stream_writable.js:375:12)
at clearBuffer (_stream_writable.js:509:5)
at onwrite (_stream_writable.js:418:7)
at WriteWrap.onWriteComplete [as oncomplete] (internal/stream_base_commons.js:103:10) {
errno: -105,
code: 'ENOBUFS',
syscall: 'write'
}
```

Here is my code:

```
const readline = require('readline')

module.exports = (job) => {
  var dsConfig = job.data.dsConfig
  var totalBytes = 0
  var procId = job.data.procId

  var params = {
    Bucket: process.env.STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME || 'xx_bucket',
    Key: dsConfig.resourceId
  }

  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    totalBytes = fs.statSync('./tmp/' + procId + '-preload.tmp').size
    var d = job.data
    if (typeof (job.data.progress) === 'undefined') {
      d.progress = 0
    }
    if (typeof (job.data.params) === 'undefined') {
      params.Range = 'bytes=0-' + totalBytes.toString()
      d.params = params
    }

    let progress = d.progress

    var chunkCounter = 0
    var totalCounter = 0
    var rowCounter = 0
    var chunkSize = 500000

    const filewriters = []
    filewriters[chunkCounter] = fs.createWriteStream('./tmp/' + d.procId + '.tmp', {
      flags: 'a', // 'a' means appending (old data will be preserved)
      encoding: 'utf8'
    })
    var outputFiles = ['./tmp/' + d.procId + '.tmp']

    function writeLine (line) {
      return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        try {
          if (totalCounter > 0) {
            filewriters[chunkCounter].write(line + '\n')
          }
          if (rowCounter > chunkSize) {
            rowCounter = 0
            chunkCounter++
            filewriters[chunkCounter] = fs.createWriteStream('./tmp/' + d.procId + '-' + chunkCounter + '.tmp', {
              flags: 'a',
              encoding: 'utf8'
            })
            outputFiles.push('./tmp/' + d.procId + '-' + chunkCounter + '.tmp')
          }
          rowCounter++
          totalCounter++
          progress += Buffer.byteLength(line + '\n', 'utf-8')
          d.params.Range = 'bytes=' + progress.toString() + '-' + totalBytes.toString()
          d.progress = progress

          job.progress(parseFloat(progress / totalBytes).toFixed(3) * 100)
          job.update(d)
          resolve()
        } catch (error) {
          reject(error)
        }
      })
    }

    try {
      var lr = readline.createInterface({
        input: fs.createReadStream('./tmp/' + procId + '-preload.tmp'),
        crlfDelay: Infinity
      })

      lr.on('line', async function (line) {
        // pause emitting of lines...
        lr.pause()
        await writeLine(line)
        lr.resume()
      })

      lr.on('close', function () {
        // All lines are read, file is closed now.
        filewriters.forEach(writer => {
          writer.end()
        })
        setTimeout(function () {
          fs.unlink('./tmp/' + procId + '-preload.tmp')
        }, 60000)
        d.tempFiles = outputFiles.reverse()
        job.update(d).then(() => {
          resolve()
        }).catch(err => {
          reject(err)
        })
      })
    } catch (err) {
      job.update(d).then(() => {
        reject(err)
      }).catch(err => {
        console.log('Error updating job data', err)
        reject(err)
      })
    }
  })
}
```

I'm running this into a docker container with mhart/alpine-node:14 and docker-compose.
I've already tried to increase the memory limit by adding:

- NODE_OPTIONS=--max-old-space-size=8192

To my docker-compose file.

I'm pretty sure there must be something wrong in the way I'm writing the lines on the files but I haven't figure out exactly what is the problem.
Does anybody have any suggestions?

Thanks,
Salvo

Comment: Did you find your solution?

Comment: I did, but the problem wasn't related to Node at all. I was using Redis and https://github.com/OptimalBits/bull to manage the jobs queue and I had Redis configured to write on the disk rather than on memory. That was causing the memory leak.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63796633/spawnsync-bin-sh-enobufs